# Media Query Not Working With Larger Viewport Sizes

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a set of social media icons at the top of my sidebar: [outtacontext](http://outtacontext.com/wp2). But I'm having trouble positioning them in the right place at different viewport sizes. Actually, it's working for all the smaller viewports but the positioning is off for the larger screens.

Here's my main css for this positioning:

```
#top #sidebar_bg .social_bookmarks {
position: absolute;
right: 69px;
z-index: 152;
margin-top: 102px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 989px) and (min-width: 768px){

#top #sidebar_bg .social_bookmarks {
right: 33px;
margin-top: 65px;
}
}
```

For some reason, with the larger screens the icons appear to get centered within the sidebar. But any media queries I make to adjust just start adding problems.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thx.

Comment: There's a very much cleaner way to position this where you want. See my example below...

Comment: What do you mean by larger viewport? With that media query you are targeting only screen between 989px and 768px. Whatever is not between that will get the *default* styles.

Comment: Maroshii, yes, I understand that. But what I am saying is that when the screen is large, it is using the default style but that is positioning it in the wrong place (but the default style is positioning it correctly for all the other sizes). I **did** use a media query for large size screens only but the problem is is that didn't work. The default style still prevailed. So, I don't understand why that lg size media query isn't working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. I had tried making a media query for what I thought was the largest viewport size. As it turns out, I wrote it for the wrong width (just "barely" wrong but you know what that means -g). The media query for positioning should have been set for a min-width of 1140 px. I had set it for 1122px. So close. LOL

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'm Argentinean, so forgive me for my English!

Here's my help...

**The HTML markup is:**

```
<div id="sidebar_bg">

    <ul class="social_bookmarks">

        <li class='twitter'>
            <a href='http://twitter.com/outtacontext'>Follow us on Twitter</a>
        </li>
        <li class='facebook'>
            <a href='http://facebook.com/chamomileteaparty'>Join our Facebook Group</a>
        </li>
        <li class='gplus'>
            <a href='https://plus.google.com/106461359737856957875/posts'>Join me on Google Plus</a>
        </li>
        <li class='linkedin'>
            <a href='http://linkedin.com/jeffgates'>Add me on Linkedin</a>
        </li>
        <li class="rss">
            <a href="http://www.outtacontext.com/wp2/feed/">RSS</a>
        </li>
        <li class="flickr">
            <a href="http://flickr.com/outtacontext">Flickr</a>
        </li>

    </ul>

</div>
```

**The CSS styles:**

```
#top #sidebar_bg {
    text-align: center; /* This will center EXACTLY on the middle the icons (acording to the #sidebar_bg width on every screen resolution */
}

#top #sidebar_bg .social_bookmarks {
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 152;
    margin-top: 102px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 989px) and (min-width: 768px){
    #top #sidebar_bg .social_bookmarks {
        margin-top: 65px;
    }
}
```

**ALTERNATIVE CSS** - if you want to put it right or left, and use media queries to determine the separation width from one of the sides, you can use this:

```
#top #sidebar_bg {
    text-align: *****; /* right or left */
}

#top #sidebar_bg .social_bookmarks {
    margin-*****: 40px; /* right or left */
    display: inline-block;
    z-index: 152;
    margin-top: 102px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 989px) and (min-width: 768px){
    #top #sidebar_bg .social_bookmarks {
        margin-*****: 25px; /* right or left */
        margin-top: 65px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Santz. But that didn't work. I don't want the icons centered over the menu below so I used your text-align: left alternative. But the icons slide off the sidebar as the viewport got smaller. I tried text-align: right. But I got the same results. I changed the px to ems and still got same results. :(